# Docker Container hang up

Tags: windows-10, docker, docker-for-windows

I started a container in Deamon mode which I wanted to stop with the regular commands:

```
docker stop [Container-ID]
```

After half an hour, nothing happened. I cancelled this command and tried the next one:

```
docker rm [Container-ID] -f
```

It did nothing too.

When I send this command now it tells me that it is already removing the container.

I also shutdown the Computer and Started it again but it took no effect.

Can somebody tell me how to stop/remove this container?

I am using:

> Windows 10
>
> Docker version 2.0.5.0

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem when services are up and at this moment restarting OS. After that It can cause hanging container that cannot be stopped.

At this moment I found workaround is to uninstall docker and install again.

Windows 10 1903

Docker 19.03.1

```
Uninstall-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
mv C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter.old 
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Force
Restart-Computer -Force
```